# Matrix multiplication with tf.sparse_matmul fails with SparseTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why does this not work:

```
pl_input = tf.sparse_placeholder('float32',shape=[None,30])
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[30,1]), dtype='float32')
layer1a = tf.sparse_matmul(pl_input, weights, a_is_sparse=True, b_is_sparse=False)
```

The error message is

`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("Placeholder_11:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("Placeholder_10:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("Placeholder_9:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

I'm hoping to create a SparseTensorValue that I retrieve batches from, then feed a batch into the pl_input.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Use `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul` in place of `tf.sparse_matmul`; look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul) for an alternative using `tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse`.

## About sparse matrices and `SparseTensors`

The problem is not specific to `sparse_placeholder`, but due to a confusion in tensorflow's terminology.

You have sparse matrices. And then you have `SparseTensor`. Both are related but different concept.

- A `SparseTensor` is a structure that indexes its values and can represent sparse matrices or tensors efficiently.
- A sparse matrix is a matrix filled mostly with `0`. In tensorflow's documentation, it often does *not* refer to a `SparseTensor` but to a plain old `Tensor` filled mostly with `0`s.

It is therefore important to look at the expected type of a function's argument to figure out.

So for example, in [the documentation of `tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_matmul), operands need to be plain `Tensor`s and not `SparseTensor`s, independently of the value of the `xxx_is_sparse` flags, which explains your error. When these flags are `True`, what `tf.sparse_matmul` actually expects really is a (dense) `Tensor`. In other words, these flags serve [some optimization purposes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/83be34c47c7ed81c62bd61a908fde017e301b578/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/matmul_op.cc#L33) and not input type constraints. (Those optimizations seem to be useful only for [rather larger matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859321/how-to-perform-efficient-sparse-matrix-multiplication-by-using-tf-matmul/44861939) by the way).